# WPF Datagrid in ScrollView Captures Row Details ComboBox Scrolling events

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid, scrollviewer

I have a datagrid inside a scrollviewer.  The rows of my datagrid can be expanded to show the details and edit the row items.

In order for the "page" to scroll when the number of rows/row details view pushes the grid too long, I am handling the PreviewMouseWheel event on the datagrid. This works until I have a combobox in my row details with a droplist that has enough items that it also needs to scroll.

When using the mouse wheel, the droplist will scroll, but so does the outer datagrid, effectively scrolling the contents "behind" the droplist and leaving the droplist in the wrong place.

My PreviewMouseWheel event handler does the following:

```
private void StampPartsDatagrid_PreviewMouseWheelForScrolling(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    StampingScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(StampingScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta / 3);
}
```

I tried to trap the dropdown/drop up event on the combo, and while that works, if I move the mouse outside the drop list and scroll with the wheel, the page doesn't scroll.

I looked through many articles on MSDN and SO but they were mostly about getting the datagrid to scroll when inside a scrollviewer.

Is there a way to do a hit test on the Preview scrolling event? Should I trap the mouse/enter leave on the droplist somehow? Should I be handling my scrolling differently?

Thanks

*** EDIT *** 
I resolved this issue. I was overthinking the mouse wheel behaviour.  By looking at the Windows settings panel page for regions, which has a very long combo list to display, I saw that if the combo list was dropped the mousewheel only applied to he dropped list. Moving the mouse outside the droplist and scrolling with the wheel has no effect.

Given this, I adopted the same behaviour by trapping the drop open /drop close events and controlling the outer scrolling. My new event handler, taken from this post (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6fc503a6-ba53-4395-b9b8-f56301efd097/mousescroll-of-combobox-scrolls-the-page-as-well?forum=wpf) is this:

```
private void StampPartsDatagrid_PreviewMouseWheelForScrolling(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    if (!bDetailsComboDropped)
    { 
        StampingScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(StampingScrollViewer.VerticalOffset - e.Delta / 3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to have an `bDetailsComboDropped` field, you can also try to determine where the preview mouse wheel routed event is coming from. Specifically, check e.[OriginalSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.originalsource?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_RoutedEventArgs_OriginalSource) to get a reference to the WPF element that was actually triggering the event (or e.Source if you find it better for the purpose).

Combine this with a recursive function using [VisualTreeHelper.GetParent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getparent?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Media_VisualTreeHelper_GetParent_System_Windows_DependencyObject_) to check whether any of the parent elements is a combo box part, or it ends with your root scroll viewer.

(Note: your solution with the Boolean flag might actually provide higher performance, I just posted this in case someone needs a source-oriented solution, e.g. if there were many other controls to check against scrolling internally, etc.)