# scrolling problem with combobox inside datagrid inside scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, event-handling, mousewheel

The UI is working, meaning the data looks good, however, we have a scrolling problem.

The data is in a series of ComboBoxes, inside of a DataGrid because we have many ComboBoxes, which is inside a ScrollViewer because the series is too long to fit the small window.

What I found out is that the DataGrid does not scroll inside the ScrollViewer, but with [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895098/1845672) this is easily fixed: add a handler for the PreviewMouseWheel event for the DataGrid that forwards (bubbles) that event to the ScrollViewer.

Now the problem moves to the ComboBoxes. When we click the ComboBox and see the ComboBoxListItems, the scrolling events reaches the ScrollViewer, probably through the added event handler. As an effect, when I try to scroll the ComboBox Item List, this has only limited effect, I can only scroll one item higher or lower. Plus, the ScrollViewer also scrolls.

To be precise, the problem refers to the scroll wheel. Scrolling by dragging the thumb in the scrollbar works perfectly. However, our users have mice with scroll wheel, and obviously expect the scroll wheel to scroll the content that the mouse is hovering over.

The obvious solution would be to add a similar event handler to the ComboBox, to handle the MouseWheel Scroll event, and to mark the event as handled with `e.Handled=True` .

However, I have no idea how to "handle" the ComboBox scroll event. If I just capture the event and mark it with `e.Handled=True`, then scrolling the combobox will not work. I found several posts on how to disable scrolling, but nothing with an example for how to handle scrolling in the ComboBox.

Here is the full source code of my small test app:

The XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="theScrollViewer">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Text="Test the Scrollwheel in the Palette" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 1"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 2"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 3"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 4"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 5"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 6"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 7"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 8"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 9"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 10"/>
        <DataGrid Name="dgProperties" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}"
                  PreviewMouseWheel="theDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnWidth="*"
                  HeadersVisibility="None"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- Left Column -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Label}" />
                <!-- Right Column -->
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
                <!-- Third column with ComboBoxes https://stackoverflow.com/a/11942357/1845672 -->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!--inline template, but could also be from Resources-->
                            <ComboBox
                                Text="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}"
                                PreviewMouseWheel="theComboBox_PreviewMouseWheel"
                                >
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Path=DisplayValue}" />
                                <ComboBoxItem>Eersel</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Tweede Jan Steenstraat</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Drievliet</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Vierhouten</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Vijfhuizen</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Zestienhoven</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Zevenaar</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Achterhoek</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Negen Straatjes</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Tiengemeten</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Elfstedenhal</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Twaalf Ambachten</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Dertienhuizen</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Amsterdam</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Haarlem</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Den Haag</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Echt</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Budel</ComboBoxItem>
                                <ComboBoxItem>Oosterhout</ComboBoxItem>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
                                >
```

The code behind:

```
    public partial class WindowTestScrolllPalette : Window
{
    private ObjectProperty OP = new ObjectProperty();

    public WindowTestScrolllPalette()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dgProperties.DataContext = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property version of ItemsSource,
    /// for Binding to control.ItemsSource.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty> Value
    {
        get { 
            return OP.GetRows("pipe");
        }
        set { return; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The original scroll event handler, on the ScrollViewer,
    /// to make the DataGrid scrollable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void theScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel_OBSOLETE(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ScrollViewer scrollView)
        {
            scrollView.UpdateLayout();
            scrollView.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scrollView.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
            e.Handled = true;
        }            
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The new (better) scroll event handler, on the DataGrid,
    /// to make the DataGrid scrollable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void theDataGrid_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Source:
        // Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78194768/wpf-datagrid-does-not-bubble-the-scrollwheel-event
        // @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work
        // A https://stackoverflow.com/a/61895098/1845672

        //what we're doing here, is that we're invoking the "MouseWheel" event of the parent ScrollViewer.

        //first, we make the object with the event arguments (using the values from the current event)
        var args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);

        //then we need to set the event that we're invoking.
        //the ScrollViewer control internally does the scrolling on MouseWheelEvent, so that's what we're going to use:
        args.RoutedEvent = ScrollViewer.MouseWheelEvent;

        //and finally, we raise the event on the parent ScrollViewer.
        theScrollViewer.RaiseEvent(args);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The hypothetical scroll event handler, on the ComboBox,
    /// to make the ComboBox scrollable
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void theComboBox_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is ComboBox cb)
        {
            var args = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta);
            args.RoutedEvent = ScrollViewer.MouseWheelEvent;
            //cb.ItemsPanel.RaiseEvents(args);//cb has no such property
            //cb.ScrollToVerticalOffset(cb.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);//cb has no such property
            //e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I make test data:

```
public class ObjectProperty : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Content for the left column of the DataGrid
    /// </summary>
    public string Label { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Content for the right column of the DataGrid
    /// </summary>
    public string DisplayValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised event when a property changes.
    /// This handler is required for classes derived from INotifyPropertyChanged.
    /// If this handler is non-null, it will be invoked by OnPropertyChanged (below).
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Method called in the 'setter' of properties whom changes have to be notified.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) =>  // NOTABENE: LAMBDA NOTATION, BUT IS THIS STILL JUST A REGULAR METHOD???
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the list of items for the datagrid
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty> GetRows(string ObjectId)
    {
        // Set up the collection properties used to bind the ItemsSource 
        // properties to display the list of items in the dropdown lists.
        string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.ffffff");
        var L = new ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>();
        switch (ObjectId.ToLower())
        {
            case "pipe":
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = "26.3 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Material", DisplayValue = "PVC" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Substance", DisplayValue = "Tar" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Address", DisplayValue = "Mainstreet" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "ObjectId", DisplayValue = ObjectId });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = ObjectId.Length.ToString() });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Time", DisplayValue = now });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Width", DisplayValue = "0.15 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Weight", DisplayValue = "16.2 kg" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Orientation", DisplayValue = "Northwest" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Flexible", DisplayValue = "Yes" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Status", DisplayValue = "Half" });
                break;

            case "line":
            default:
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = "1.23 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Material", DisplayValue = "PVC" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Substance", DisplayValue = "Tar" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Address", DisplayValue = "Backstreet" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "ObjectId", DisplayValue = ObjectId });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Length", DisplayValue = ObjectId.Length.ToString() });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Time", DisplayValue = now });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Width", DisplayValue = "0.15 m" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Weight", DisplayValue = "16.2 kg" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Orientation", DisplayValue = "Northwest" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Flexible", DisplayValue = "Yes" });
                L.Add(new ObjectProperty() { Label = "Status", DisplayValue = "Half" });
                break;
        };
        return L;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Return the list of items for the datagrid as a Key Values Pair
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ObjectId"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>> GetRows_KVP(string ObjectId)
    {
        var items = GetRows(ObjectId);
        var itemsKvp = new KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>>(ObjectId, items);
        return itemsKvp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The entire dataset for display in the UserControl
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>>> TheItemsSource()
    {
        var itemsSource = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>>>();
        itemsSource.Add(GetRows_KVP("Pipe"));
        itemsSource.Add(GetRows_KVP("Line"));
        return itemsSource;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property version of ItemsSource,
    /// for assigning to control.ItemsSource.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string, ObservableCollection<ObjectProperty>>> TheItemsSourceProperty {
        get { return TheItemsSource(); }
        set { return; }
    }

}
```

Here is the screenshot: with the mouse hovering over, e.g., "Negen Straatjes", the scrollwheel will fully scroll the DataGrid, while the ComboBox item list only "scrolls" one item, at max between "Negen Straatjes" and "Tiengemeten":

[image: screenshot of ComboBox inside DataGrid inside ScrollViewer]

As for the `DataGrid Height`: in the above sources I tried in the XAML to add a Height of 400, and removed both PreviewMouseWheel events from DataGrid and ComboBox; the result was that the scroll wheel only worked over the TextBox rows, not over the DataGrid. So the DataGrid definitely needs the event handler.

As a reference, here is another test app, really simple, with no special code in code-behind. The scrolling works on all levels, however, it is a bit funny how the focus moves between ScrollViewer and ComboBox, e.g. by tabbing between input controls, but I guess it is all very logical:

```
<Window x:Class="xaml_test.Palettes.Views.WindowTestScrollwheel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xaml_test.Palettes.Views"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="WindowTestScrollwheel" Width="350" Height="250" >
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBox Text="Test the Scrollwheel" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 1"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 2"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 3"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 4"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 5"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 6"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 7"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 8"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 9"/>
        <TextBox Text="Row 10"/>
        <ComboBox Text="City?" MaxDropDownHeight="150">
            <ComboBoxItem>Eersel</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Tweede Jan Steenstraat</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Drievliet</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Vierhouten</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Vijfhuizen</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Zestienhoven</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Zevenaar</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Achterhoek</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Negen Straatjes</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Tiengemeten</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Elfstedenhal</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Twaalf Ambachten</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Dertienhuizen</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Amsterdam</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Haarlem</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Den Haag</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Echt</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Budel</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Oosterhout</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 2">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 3">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 4">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 5">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 6">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 7">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 8">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 9">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox Text="cb 10">
            <ComboBoxItem>One</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Two</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Three</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
        <TextBox Text="Row 11" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 12" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 13" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 14" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 15" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 16" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 17" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 18" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 19" />
        <TextBox Text="Row 20" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: You did not explain the original problem. What behavior are you observing and what do you expect? Also add example code that shows the actual layout that causes the problem, please.

Comment: *"What I found out is that the DataGrid does not scroll inside the ScrollViewer,"* - You must give the DataGrid a Height. Otherwise, it will stretch to infinity causing the scroll viewer to not show up and also disables UI virtualization causing all rows to be immediately loaded into memory.

Comment: And in general, you should *always* be able to scroll when moving the mouse pointer over the scroll bar that you want to move.

Comment: @BionicCode please look at the complete source code I just added, and the clarification of the expected and erroneous scrolling behaviour.

Comment: @BionicCode I tested with DataGrid Height, as you suggested, but it did not remove the need for the PreviewMouseWheel event on the DataGrid :-(

Comment: This is definitely a related post, I will try it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59863778/wpf-datagrid-in-scrollview-captures-row-details-combobox-scrolling-events

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I still don't find the explanation of the original problem (without your attempts to fix it). I have run your first example and it behaves just normal for me - when I remove all the mouse wheel handling. If I set the Height of the DataGrid so that it can't display all its rows, the scroll viewer appears and I can use it to scroll through the hidden rows. When I open the ComboBox I can scroll through its items. There is nothing wrong. Please describe your *original* problem you are trying to solve and not the current problem introduced by your event handling.

Comment: Your current problem is introduced by the way you handle the MouseWheel event. Because you raise it the parent ScrollViewer (the DataGrid)  will handle it and perform the scroll while you are scrolling the ComboBox. This doesn't make sense and you obviously also don't want this to happen. Leaves the question (still): why were you doing it in the first place? When the mouse is over the ComboBox it will scroll exclusively. That's the normal behavior. Do you want a different behavior?

Comment: @BionicCode without the mouse wheel handling, I can scroll, using the scrollbar, but not using the mousewheel. The scrollwheel stops working as soon as the DataGrid appears under the mouse. This is the original problem. After adding the mouse wheel handling, the problem moves to the combobox item list. Are we working in different versions of wpf?? Mine is Visual Studio 2022 Pro, .NET 4.8

Comment: Now I understand. I wasn't considering this behavior as a problem as this is the Windows default.: the mouse wheel only scrolls the content the mouse is hovering over. If the mouse pointer hovers over the DataGrid the mouse wheel is handled by the DataGrid. The user must move the mouse pointer over the scroll bar to move the "focus" away from the DataGrid to the parent ScrollViewer.

Comment: Now you want to change the default behavior and continue scrolling? It will lead to some undesirable behavior. For example, when the user scrolls through a list and reaches the end, the parent scroll viewer will move the list out of the view. This can be pretty annoying I guess.

Comment: @BionicCode Yes and no. Everybody expects the content to scroll where the mouse is hovering. But in the above case, with the mouse hovering over the dropdown from the combobox, the mouse wheel scrolls not the combobox dropdown list, but the datagrid underneath the combobox. That is clearly wrong. That is the "original problem" here

Comment: But this is not reproducible. What you describe now is only happening with you extra mouse wheel event handling logic. When I remove all your event handlers and move the mouse over the drop down it scrolls exclusively. The DataGrid doesn't scroll. I thought we were talking about the case when the DataGrid has no scroll viewer and the mouse is over the element you want to scroll using the parent scroll viewer.

Comment: I really want to help but I'm confused. To make it clear, I don't intend to fix your current event handling implementation as it is logically wrong and technically wrong. I would provide a different solution. I have the feeling you are confusing the two scenarios:  the original and the one that already contains your attempt to fix the behavior by handling the MouseWheel event.

Comment: The original scenario is the vanilla code. In the case of the example this is a non-scrollable DataGrid that contains scrollable ComboBox elements, all are children of the parent root ScrollViewer you named `"theScrollViewer"`. And in this scenario scrolling the ComboBox does not scroll the DataGrid. __But moving the mouse over the DataGrid won't scroll `"theScrollViewer"`__. Is that your problem?

Comment: @BionicCode I tried with DataGrid Height=400, and saw no improvement. But with Height=200, it DOES work better: the DataGrid gets its own vertical scrollbar, and the mousewheel works better, without the handler. But I can probably also get rid of the ScrollViewer now. The TextBox rows were only added for testing, but not really needed. Thanks so far for your comments!!!